# What is the problem with this code?

Tags: c++, static

```
#include<stdio.h>

class A { public: int a;};
class B: public A { 
public:
    static int b;
    B(){
        b++;
        printf("B:%d\n",b);
    }   
};

int main() {

    A* a1 = new B[100];
    A* a2 = new B();
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
In function `main':
undefined reference to `B::b'
undefined reference to `B::b'
undefined reference to `B::b'
undefined reference to `B::b'
```

Comment: I see this question about 10 times in a week :D

Comment: @Simon: on SO? can you post links to those questions? I'll have a look and probably learn something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Static variables need to be allocated outside the class. Add this line outside the class B:

```
int B::b;
```

Think of static variables as being declared with the `extern` keyword. They still need to be allocated somewhere. This means the allocation should never be in the header file!

Comment: actually, allocation can be there in a header file, if that file is used at-most one place in a program (to avoid linking errors). Am I correct?

Comment: @Lazer: indeed, but that defeat the purpose of a header file, that is to be included in more than one file.

Comment: yeah you are correct, I just wanted to check whether I understood that right! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because it is static, you also need to define storage for `B::b` (in a class definition, all you have done is declared the variable).

You need to add:

```
int B::b;
```

Comment: I disagree, B::b has no value whether it's static or not, that will still fail.

Comment: @Silmaril89: "Has no value"? What is it supposed to mean? Objects with static storage duration in C++ are always zero-initialized. In this case `B::b` is guaranteed to be zero at program startup.

Comment: @AndreyT: That is not true. PODs are never initialized in C++ unless explicitly specified. In this case, the declaration just allocate the memory, but doesn't initialize it.

Comment: @Silmaril89 - you are incorrect.  To quote the spec: 9.4.2/7 - `Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local objects (3.6.2, 3.6.3).`  And in 3.6.2/1 - `Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)`

Comment: @PierreBdR - that is only true for automatic variables.  Static and global variables are 0 initialized by default.

Comment: @PierreBdR: Absolutely incorrect. One more time: all objects with static storage duration are always guaranteed to be properly automatically *zero-initialized* before any other initialization begins. It does not matter whether you initialize them explicitly or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your static member in the according .cpp file like int B::b = 0

Comment: You don't have to initialize objects with static storage duration to `0` - they are guaranteed to be zero-initialized automatically in any case. What is missing in OP's case is the *definition* of the object. Whether it is initialized explicitly does not immediately matter.

Comment: Perhaps you can get away without initializing but it won't hurt and it makes the code clearer.